# orderBy angularJS inside ng-switch inside ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a ng-repeat using ng-switch to seperate sections inside of the ng-repeat, I want to apply a orderby filter on the ng-switch group but i can't seem to make it work:

```
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    I have {{friends.length}} friends. They are:
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="friend in sortedFriends">
          <ng-switch on="$first || friend.age != sortedFriends[$index-1].age">
              <div ng-switch-when="true" class="group">Group of {{friend.age}} years old.  Previous: <i>{{sortedFriends[$index-1].age}}</i></div>
          </ng-switch>
          <b>[{{$index + 1}}]</b> {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old.
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/CvKNc/)
any ideas?

something like this is what I'm trying to achive:

```
   <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    I have {{friends.length}} friends. They are:
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="friend in sortedFriends | orderBy:predicate">
          <ng-switch on="$first || friend.age != sortedFriends[$index-1].age" ng-click="predicate = 'age'; reverse=!reverse">
              <div ng-switch-when="true" class="group">Group of {{friend.age}} years old.  Previous: <i>{{sortedFriends[$index-1].age}}</i></div>
          </ng-switch>
          <b>[{{$index + 1}}]</b> {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old.
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Updated Fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/CvKNc/58/

Comment: what is the output you expect? can you add the desired output manually to the bottom of your fiddle?

Comment: Do you want to achieve same result without using sortedFriends array?

Comment: with or without the ng-click needs to come from within the ng-repeat and it must maintain the ng-switch which is what is driving me mad..

Comment: your last comment made it even more confusing, what ng-click you are talking about?

Comment: Sorry! I'll update the question to make it more clear.1

Comment: updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CvKNc/44/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54338/discussion-between-vimes1984-and-quad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

result of the discussion:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Quadraxas/CvKNc/60/)

this sorts by age and changes order on click
and clicking group names orders by name

since you are checking like

```
friend.age != friends[$index-1].age
```

you can't use orderBy in ng-repeat, because ng-repeat uses an ordered array returned by the filter but you are checking from intial unordered array

best way to this is using a scope function to do the ordering

```
$scope.orderFriends = function(ageOrder,nameOrder){
    return orderByFilter($scope.friends,[ageOrder,nameOrder]);
}
```

ageOrder and nameOrder takes values like `"+age"`,`"-name"` and so on.

note that clicking on group titles changes name order for all groups.

I would ultimately, groups friends with a grouping function (using something like underscorejs) and use orderby filter for names and ages. So that names can be indivudally ordered inside groups.
 ([FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Quadraxas/CvKNc/61/), grouping probably can be done better, but the basic idea is there)

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you are looking for but if you need to sort further within your array, you can use an array for your orderBy definition.

```
['+age','name']
```

http://jsfiddle.net/csrow/BaqEg/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/csrow/CvKNc/62/  Try this to see if this is what you are looking for.